# What server does the knife.rb connect to?

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I don't have access to the `knife.rb` file and therefore cannot view the file's content (I cannot see the `knife.rb` file inside the `.chef` folder)

How do I find out what server `knife` connects to?

Answer (score 2):

Just by ssl check command:

```sh
$ knife ssl check --verbose
```